# paypal sandbox. 10609 Transaction id is invalid

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

What am I doing wrong?
I use a PayPal Payments Pro sandbox test account.

1. I execute `DoDirectPayment() where PaymentAction=PaymentActionCodeType.Authorization`
2. I receive "Success" and `TransactionID`
3. I execute `DoVoid() where AuthorizationID = TransactionID` from step 2
4. I receive `"10609 Transaction id is invalid."`

The same with `DoAuthorization()`.

1. I execute `DoDirectPayment() where PaymentAction=PaymentActionCodeType.Order`
2. I receive "Success" and `TransactionID`
3. I execute `DoAuthorization() where TransactionID = TransactionID` from step 2
4. I receive "`10609 Transaction id is invalid."`

**UPD:**
`<DoDirectPaymentRequest><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">95.0</Version><DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents"><PaymentAction>Sale</PaymentAction><PaymentDetails><OrderTotal currencyID="USD">951</OrderTotal></PaymentDetails><CreditCard><CreditCardNumber>4998275181667886</CreditCardNumber><ExpMonth>12</ExpMonth><ExpYear>2017</ExpYear><CardOwner><PayerName><FirstName>Nazar</FirstName><LastName>Nazar</LastName></PayerName><Address><Street1>dfgdfgdfg</Street1><CityName>Manhattan</CityName><StateOrProvince>NY</StateOrProvince><Country>US</Country><PostalCode>10005</PostalCode></Address></CardOwner><CVV2>030</CVV2></CreditCard></DoDirectPaymentRequestDetails></DoDirectPaymentRequest></DoDirectPaymentReq>`

`<DoDirectPaymentResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2012-12-06T15:23:13Z</Timestamp><Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Success</Ack><CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">32db76f5d7828</CorrelationID><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">95.0</Version><Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">4137385</Build><Amount xsi:type="cc:BasicAmountType" currencyID="USD">951.00</Amount><AVSCode xsi:type="xs:string">X</AVSCode><CVV2Code xsi:type="xs:string">M</CVV2Code><TransactionID>1R649887J67078538</TransactionID></DoDirectPaymentResponse>`

*sorry, copied not all*
**UPD2:** 
`<DoVoidReq xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><DoVoidRequest><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">95.0</Version><AuthorizationID>1R649887J67078538</AuthorizationID></DoVoidRequest></DoVoidReq>`

`<DoVoidResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI"><Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2012-12-06T15:23:15Z</Timestamp><Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Failure</Ack><CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">f8795daa4b104</CorrelationID><Errors xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:ErrorType"><ShortMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Invalid transactionID.</ShortMessage><LongMessage xsi:type="xs:string">Transaction id is invalid.</LongMessage><ErrorCode xsi:type="xs:token">10609</ErrorCode><SeverityCode xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Error</SeverityCode></Errors><Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">95.0</Version><Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">4181146</Build><AuthorizationID xsi:type="xs:string"></AuthorizationID></DoVoidResponse>`

Comment: Can you provide samples of the actual API requests that are getting generated?  That's only way to see exactly what's going on.  Invalid transaction ID is pretty straight forward, so we just need to see exactly what's getting passed into the actual request.

Comment: The first method you outlined should be working fine, but again, just need to see the actual DoVoid request.  The second method you outlined is incorrect.  Yo wouldn't use DoAuthorization after DoDirectPayment.  You would use either DoVoid or DoCapture.

Comment: `DoCapture()` made same error.

Comment: Ok, so again, need to get a look at the actual request that's being generated, not just the SDK code.  The class library will make the RAW API request and response available one way or another.  It'll either be XML or an NVP string.

Comment: Mabye some wrong with account settings, but `sale` working fine.

Comment: Ah, I see you updated the OP to show the full thing.  I use DoVoid with NVP a lot and I've never had any issues.  I'd recommend posting this to www.paypal.com/mts.  Show them the same samples you showed me here and they should be able to get it resolved for you.

Comment: Ok.
Thank you for help. I'll try post it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DoVoid request doesn't look quite right.  You've got...

```
<DoVoidRequest>
  <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">95.0</Version>
  <AuthorizationID>1R649887J67078538</AuthorizationID>
</DoVoidRequest>
</DoVoidReq>
```

It should be...

```
<DoVoidReq>
    <DoVoidRequest>
      <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">95.0</Version>
      <AuthorizationID>1R649887J67078538</AuthorizationID>
    </DoVoidRequest>
</DoVoidReq>
```